# Error in Spring Configuration when not connected to the internet

Tags: spring

I have my Spring Configuration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
```

This works fine when the server is connected to the internet. However, if the access is revoked, the following error happens:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [spring/applicationContext-service-webapp.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "http-equiv".

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some different version of one of the included schemas are being loaded or the schema is not accessible/loaded at all.

---

**UPDATED**
Excluding the duplicated artifact in your pom file will resolve the problem.

Comment: I checked the my `Maven Dependencies` jar files, and it turns out there are two versions of `spring-aop`. Both `2.5.6` and `3.1.0` are available. What I currently need (which I added to the `pom.xml`) is `3.1.0`. The other version is being loaded because of some `jersey` jar file. Is this (having 2 different versions) causing the problem?

Comment: Yea, that's right. The problem was with `spring-aop 2.5.6`. I exclude it and the problem is resolved. Now `spring-aop 3.1.0` jar file is being loaded locally.